# Committing a remote configuration to a git repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, configuration

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this, can I "preset" (i.e., commit) a remote to a Git repository so that when it is cloned, the cloned repository also has the remote without having to `remote add` it?

Here's the use case. I want to fork node and make changes that only my team needs (i.e., that would be inappropriate to merge back into the upstream repository). I also want my team to be able to periodically merge new changes from the original repository. In other words:

1. On github.com: fork [github.com/joyent/node](https://github.com/joyent/node) → github.com/[me]/node
2. On my local machine: `git clone https://github.com/[me]/node.git`
3. On my local machine: `git add remote upstream https://github.com/joyent/node.git`
4. [`branch`, hack, `merge`, `fetch upstream`, `push`, etc.]...

So far so good.

What I *really* want is to "commit" and "push" the `upstream` remote configuration so the next time someone does `git clone https://github.com/[me]/node.git`, they don't have to also do `git add remote upstream https://github.com/joyent/node.git` (i.e., it's already set for the cloned repository).

I see that `git` has a specialized notion of being able to commit submodule configurations (see [`gitmodules[5]`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)), but I can't find a generic option for arbitrary configuration overrides. I realize this is probably by design, since it risks misuse (imagine a preset override of `user.email`).

Any help is appreciated, even if it's just: "Nope, sorry. Your team is going to have to type `git add remote upstream ...` for every cloned repo. [Citation.]"

Comment: Git clone --template or wrapper script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally minutes after submitting this question, I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153464/commit-changes-to-git-configuration) (which I didn't find in my initial search).

Basically, it says that `git add remote upstream ...` must be run, (or `.git/config` must be edited) for every cloned repo. As @AndrewC points out, this can be automated with a [wrapper] script.

This seems clunky to me, but I will accept that fixing `upstream` remotes is probably a bad idea.